# How to open .TLS files on mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I have a Browning game camera that takes timelapse photos... I was disappointed to discover it records them as huge 1-2 GB .TLS files that require software Browning makes to open, and it only works on windows.

[Browning suggests](https://browningtrailcameras.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206232377-Is-the-Buck-Watch-Timelapse-Viewer-software-available-for-Mac-users-) Mac users change the files to .AVI, which doesn't work. Are there any other options to open these files or are they inaccessible to Mac users?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to change it to AVI - just rename it back and then drag it into a player like VLC.

That software will look inside the file and try to read the header and tell you which encoding and packaging scheme is needed.

Once you know the files are correct and play or can get more details, perhaps a follow on question explaining why VLC won’t open it might make sense.

- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html

If you like VLC - then right click on one of the files and choose Open with... and reset all TLC files to open in VLC - you should be set.